# Tikz - Block Diagrams with Matrices and Chains

Tags: matrices, chain

I'm trying to draw block diagrams with tikz.
For that I'd like to use matrices to align the nodes and then connect the nodes with the tikzlibrary `chains`, as described in the pgfmanual page 601 (chapter 48).

However, within some blocks I'd like to place custom pictograms. Once I do that, I cannot chain blocks containing custom pictograms together.

I've got the idea from this [texample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/BER-measurement/), which I cannot get to compile either.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes, matrix}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% I'd like to have a block with two circles within
\def\circles{
    \node{};
    \draw (-1mm,0) circle(2mm) (2mm,0) circle(2mm);
}

\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, 
    nodes={draw,
        minimum size=1cm,
        align=center,
        anchor=center},
    column sep=1cm,
    row sep=1cm,
]
{
    A & B & C & \circles \\
};

{ [start chain, every on chain/.style={join=by ->}]
    \chainin (m-1-1);
    \chainin (m-1-2);
    \chainin (m-1-3);
%   \chainin (m-1-4); % once uncommented, it doesn't compile
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the code as is I get the following result:
[image: so far so good]

Once I uncomment the last `\chainin (m-1-4);` statement though, I get the error message

```
[LaTeX] Line 87: Package pgf Error: No shape named `chain-1' is known.
[LaTeX] Line 87: See the pgf package documentation for explanation. ...                                                                                                
l.80    \chainin (m-1-4);
```

Any idea how I could connect a node with such a pictogram within a chaining sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  understood you correctly than you are after the following:

[image]

MWE, which produce above images, use only `arrows.meta`, `chains` and `positioning` libraries. Arrows between nodes are drawn by macro `join` defined in `chains` library.,

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                positioning}
\newcommand\dcircle{\tikz{\draw (-0.1,0) circle[radius=2mm] (0.1,0) circle[radius=2mm]}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm and 1cm,
  start chain = going right,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum size=1cm, semithick,
                 on chain, join=by ->}
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\x] in {A, B , C, \dcircle}
\node [N] {\i};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the problem with my example was how I defined the dual circles.

Comment: @bsng, frankly said. I didn't understood your definition of circles, so I write another (to my opinion) simpler solution. I'm glad that it help you!